# How to instantiante and manipulate arrays (and variables in general) in a constructor class

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

http://pastebin.com/xBqdUtTg - main
http://pastebin.com/BadasC7N - constructor

I have to create a method in the constructor file that adds a player to an array, but I'm not allowed to change the code fragments given in the above items. My problem is that I don't know how to instantiate the array with the correct size which is given through user input because I have to stick with the framework of addAPlayer(String playername) and can't add in a parameter to decide length. Also I don't know how to manipulate variables in a constructor

```
public class Practice{
    public Practice(){
        int x;
        int y;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Practice prac = new Practice();
        prac.x = 1;
        prac.y = 2;
    }
}
```

that doesn't work so what other way am I to manipulate those variables? in the stub code that I was given for homework there are class variables but they're labeled as private so I can't change them directly, and the parameters for the constructor are already given so I can't define them there

edit: also a for loop in the main file calls the method addAPlayer every time it goes through in order to set the correct number of player names which are entered via user input, but how can I make sure that each time it calls that method it sets a different index of the array equal to the name

edit:

```
    public class NBATeam {
    private String sTeamName;
    private int nWin;
    private int nLoss;
    private String [] playerArray;
    //Your code here

    }//end of class definition
```

^^^ constructor class

```
    //Warning: Do not change the given codes
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NBA {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

            //construct Team Heat
            NBATeam heat= new NBATeam("Heats");
             System.out.print("How many players Heats own: ");
             Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
             int numberOfPlayers = input.nextInt();

            // Prompt user to enter players into the Team
             for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++) {
                   System.out.print("Enter the name of Player #" + (i + 1) + ": ");
                   String playerName = input.next();
                   heat.addAPlayer(playerName);
             }

            //construct Team Spurs


             //Your code here
```

Comment: Please copy the relevant code into your question instead of providing pastebin links.

Comment: your posted code shows creating local variables in a constructor, which doesn't seem like what you want.

Comment: there you go, not sure why everyone dislikes pastebin links though

Comment: it's inconvenient to have to follow a link. some people are answering from work and can't access sites like that. also it's better for everybody to have the OP create an MVCE than dump their code on pastebin.

Comment: Well I feel like I need to know how to create local variables in a constructor to properly complete this homework so I just threw that in as a secondary question

Comment: @H.Guy:  The goal of this site is to create an archive of questions and answers. What good would this question (or its answers) be years from now, after the pastebin.com links have vanished?

Answer (score 0):

Don't create an instance of NBA team unless you know how many players you are adding. This is all assuming that you can't use a List<>.

```
on line 12:
NBATeam heat= new NBATeam("Heats", numberOfPlayers);
```

Then in class NBATeam add:

```
int currentIndex;
public NBATeam(String name, int numberOfPlayers) {
    sTeamName = name;
    playerArray = new String[numberOfPlayers];
}
public void addAPlayer(String playerName) {
    playerArray[currentIndex] = playerName;
    currentIndex++;
}
```

Again, this is all a bit error-prone, as you should check if addAPlayer is called too often. You also need to account for the playerArray not completely filled etc.
You also would need to check if numberOfPlayers passed into the ctor is a valid value, etc.

Better to use a List<> for that, but since you have to use the array in your sample code, you gotta add all those checks (left as an exercise to the reader)

Comment: the problem with that is that I'm restricted by the parameters my professor gave me. I'm only allowed to use 1 parameter in the constructor and that parameter is the name

Comment: if the lesson here is to learn about arrays and that they don't just extend in length, then you basically need to re-allocate playerArray for each call to addAPlayer, copy the old array to the new one and add the new player.

Which is ugly as hell and wasteful.

Comment: and how would I change a variable inside a constructor from outside a constructor

Comment: in the constructor you start with playerArray = new String[0];.
in addAPlayer you would have something like:

    `playerArray = Arrays.copyOf(playerArray, playerArray.length + 1);`
    `playerArray[playerArray.length - 1] = playerName;`